# Inno Setup "return" like command/construct in Code

Tags: inno-setup, return-value, pascalscript, function-exit

Is there any command/construct like `return` in C that exits immediately from a function of Inno Setup script code keeping the result code?

I would like something

```pascal
If k = false then
Begin
    Result:=false;
    Exit;
End;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Use the [`Exit` statement](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/exit.html) to exit a `function` or a `procedure`. With the `function`, set the `Result` automatic variable, before you call the `Exit`, to set the return value.

```pascal
function MyFunction: Boolean;
begin
  if not SomeTest then
  begin
    // cannot do stuff, aborting
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  // do stuff

  Result := True;
end;
```